# jquery function always return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

i'm using jquery to validate a form using ajax to check if the old password is correct then compare the new password to the confirm password input but the function always return false the submit button doesn't work at all here's the code (the returned data from ajax is correct i've checked it)

```
function check_pwd() {
    var pass = $("#oldPWD").val();
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", "ajax/check_pass.php?pass=" + pass);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            result = ajax.responseText;
            if (result.indexOf('wrong') !== -1) {
                alert("wrong password");
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send(null);
}

function confirmPwd() {
    var pwd1 = $("#newPWD").val();
    var pwd2 = $("#newPWD2").val();
    if (pwd1 !== pwd2) {
        alert("do not match");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function check_form() {
    if (!check_pwd() || !confirmPwd()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are combining asynchronous call with a synchronous call..!

Comment: Isn't it ``$.ajax(..)`` and why not using ``$.ajax().success(function() {...})``?

Comment: it returns the word correct or wrong

Comment: You can't return a value from inside a callback to the outer check_pwd function! That is in a different scope.

Comment: so how can I return true or false inside ajax?

Comment: You insert callbacks on the success, or use jQuery promises. Start with `$.ajax()` of `$.post()` instead of your current code and research them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggest i'll use it

Answer (score 1):

Make new password validation when the old one is already veryfied.

```
function confirmPwd() {
    var pwd1 = $("#newPWD").val();
    var pwd2 = $("#newPWD2").val();
    if (pwd1 !== pwd2) {
        alert("do not match");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function check_form() {
    var pass = $("#oldPWD").val();
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", "ajax/check_pass.php?pass=" + pass);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            result = ajax.responseText;
            if (result.indexOf('wrong') !== -1) {
                alert("wrong password");
                return false;
            } else {
                confirmPwd();
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send(null);

    if (!check_pwd() || !confirmPwd()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i get this idea but the form is submitted without entering any data

Comment: Weird process but you can call check_form() when your page is loaded.